# heatmap Highcharts tickmarkPlacement yAxis

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

Is it possible to get the tickmark exactly on its value, and not in the middle of the hour? In my heatmap I have 1/4h values, so the tickmark position doesn't make sense. To illustrate this, I take a sample of Highcharts and make a little modification:
https://jsfiddle.net/wczo89Le/1/

Definition of the yAxis:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value}:00'
    },
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18, 23],
    tickWidth: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 23
},
```

Consider the 2 first hours in the charts. There are 1/4 value. But the tick of 00:00 is on 00:30.
Antoher problem is the tooltip doesn't show the value where the mouse is. But it is offset. So it's not possible to get the last value (23:45) in the day shown in the tooltip.

Many thanks

Comment: I have a workaround for the first problem. But is there an easier solution?

    `tickPositions: [-0.5, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5],
    labels: {
            formatter: function () { return (this.value + 0.5) + ":00"; }
    },`
https://jsfiddle.net/wczo89Le/2/

Comment: You need to set rowsize, by default it is equaled 1. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cheatmap%3E.rowsize). If you want to have squares with the height of 0.25, set rowsize to that value. You can specify tickInterval to 0.25, but if you do not have enough height for the chart, the overlapping ticks will be hide. see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ucst9o7g/)